# Do I really need to add Roth IRA contribution information to my tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, form-8606

I've never quite understood what the purpose of a contribution form was for a post-tax contribution to a Roth IRA. I'm not getting a deduction for it or anything, after all. Is there any consequence if a person were to forget to document a Roth contribution in income tax filings?

Comment: Note that you're not allowed to contribute to a Roth IRA (or only allowed to contribute a partial amount) if you make over a certain income limit. It may be more about that.

Comment: I guess the other thing is, you're not allowed to contribute more than you earned by working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the IRS instructions for [Form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606/ch01.html):

> **Penalty for Not Filing**
>
> If you are required to file Form 8606
>   to report a nondeductible contribution
>   to a traditional IRA for 2010, but do
>   not do so, you must pay a $50 penalty,
>   unless you can show reasonable cause.
>
> **Overstatement Penalty**
>
> If you overstate your nondeductible
>   contributions, you must pay a $100
>   penalty, unless you can show
>   reasonable cause.

Comment: All I have is a form 5498 documenting the contributions I've made. It doesn't look like 8606 is necessary then?

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to make any withdrawals prior to age 59-1/2, you first withdraw deposits, no tax due. Beyond that, there's an early withdrawal penalty, 10% tax on that amount. The form is the way to track cumulative deposits.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience I did not have to show any documentation for a Roth contribution, since its being done with post tax dollars. And once the money is in the Roth it anyways completely sheltered from future taxes. I file taxes using Turbo Tax and I have a Roth account since the last few years.